# Error window.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).load(function() {

        window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() { scrollBy(0, -50);});
        var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -50);};
        if (location.hash) shiftWindow();
        window.addEventListner("hashchange", shiftWindow);
    });  

});
```

works great but I'm getting an error on my home page stating "error window.addEventListener isn't not a function. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong. did I not close this loop right or something?

Comment: Typo Line 8: addEventListner

Comment: Awww, hahaa, that's it Sean, thanks dude I didn't see I had miss spelled that. works like a charm now. thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery!

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() { scrollBy(0, -50);});
```